Inertia.js preserveScroll not preserving scroll position for menu in Vue 3
I'm working on a Vue 3 project using Inertia.js, and I have a menu on the left side with scrollable content and a main content area on the right. The menu and content areas have independent scrolls, and I want to preserve the scroll position of the menu when navigating between pages.
However, despite using the preserveScroll: true option, the scroll position of the menu is not being preserved when I navigate to different routes.
Here is a simplified version of my setup:

Inertia setup:

import './bootstrap';
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import {resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import {ZiggyVue} from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy';

import plugins from "@/Plugins/index.js";
import store from './store';
const appName = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_NAME || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
 title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
 resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
 setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
  return createApp({render: () => h(App, props)})
   .use(plugin)
   .use(store)
   .use(ZiggyVue)
   .use(plugins)
   .mount(el);
 },
 progress: {
  color: '#4B5563',
 },
});


2.Component with menu and main content:
<script setup>
import {Head, router, usePage, Link} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import {nextTick, ref, onMounted} from 'vue';
import {useStore} from "vuex";

const store = useStore();
const menu = ref(null); 

const menuItems = [
 { name: 'Home', href: 'dashboard.index' },
 { name: 'Profile', href: 'profile.index' },
 { name: 'Settings', href: 'settings.index' },
 { name: 'About', href: 'abouts.index' },
 { name: 'Posts', href: 'posts.index' },
];

</script>

<template>
 <div class="flex w-full h-screen">
  <aside
   class="w-1/4 bg-gray-800 text-white p-4 overflow-y-auto"
   ref="menu"
   scroll-region
  >
   <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in menuItems" :key="index" class="mb-4">
     <Link :href="route(item.href)" class="block p-2 hover:bg-gray-700" preserve-scroll preserve-state>
      {{ item.name }}
     </Link>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </aside>
  
  <main class="flex-1 bg-gray-100 p-4 overflow-y-auto">
   <slot />
  </main>
 </div>
</template>


